# How to remove the "comments" label from Disqus' comments count script

Tags: javascript, disqus

I hope its ok to post this here. I am trying to remove the "comments" label from comment count generated by Disqus eg. "2 Comments". I want it to be just "2"

the js generating the count is http://mediacdn.disqus.com/1296789872/build/system/count.js if I am not wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change this from your Disqus Account -> Settings -> Appearance